methodology diagram

Requirement Gathering: Customers conduct requirement analysis.

Framework Design:

Incorporate input from customers and requirements analysis.
Includes database setup.


AI and ML Implementation:

Utilize frameworks for:

NLP
LLM
Speech-to-text
Computer Vision
Sentiment Analysis


Incorporate role selection and facilitate scheduling and feedback loops.


Interface Development:

Develop UI to:

Allow role selection.
Facilitate interview scheduling.
Enable real-time feedback.




Improvement and Testing:

Test the implemented system.
Iterate and improve based on results.


Configuration and Feedback:

Gather final feedback for continuous updates.



